# Debugging C with Tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a project written in C and Tcl and I'm trying to debug it. The main part is written in C, and GUI is written in Tcl. I'm new to Tcl. I tried to use lldb to debug it, but as soon as the C program calls

```
Tk_Main(TKARGS, myargv, Tcl_AppInit);
```

lldb does not work at all, even if some Tcl commands are written in C. How can I debug it?

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Can you set a breakpoint in a C-function & it will be reached?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't try breakpoints before and just tried to step through the code. Breakpoints work.

Comment: @deets: That should be an answer. Perhaps with a comment about events being asynchronous and the event loop running when nothing else is running making it necessary to debug using breakpoints?

Comment: But my program has a bug and when using lldb, it crashes at some assembly code. I think it might be the Tcl part. How can I debug the Tcl part?

Comment: You jump to conclusions. What does the stacktrace say? Use the "bt"command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging C/C++ and a scripting-language together, you can't expect LLDB to know how to source-level-debug both. It only knows about C/C++ (or more precisely, DWARF-symbols).

Thus if you expect your C-code to be faulty when being invoked from within the Script-language, you need to set a breakpoint & then operate the program to trigger the call.

When crashes appear, you should use the "bt"-command to get a clue where in the stacktrace you are, and investigate further using breakpoints.

Comment: I just learned the bt command, it turns out to be very useful! My program is called psim and I think I know which C function to set breakpoint next. The bt command gives   * frame #0: 0x00007fff8f2f9286 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8b83d42f libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
    frame #2: 0x00007fff870eeb53 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 129
...
    frame #5: 0x0000000100001c6e psim`simResetCmd(clientData=0x0000000000000000, interp=, argc=1, argv=0x0000000101032a90) + 110 at psim.c:870
    frame #6: Tcl`TclInvokeStringCommand + 124

Comment: I have a long-term plan to teach lldb how to handle Tcl, but it's vastly non-trivial and not something that helps the questioner…